# C# type check using 'is not' operator not working

Tags: c#, dynamic, types

I'm doing this boolean check that doesn't work and I don't really get why.

I have a variable: `dynamic value;`
Let's say this variable is of type `BuiltInClass`.
Now I'm doing this check:

```
if (value is not BuiltInClass || value is not ClassValue)
{
    // Execute code
}
```

But this code still executes.
Can anyone please explain?

Comment: What about `if(!(value is BuiltInClass || value is ClassValue))`, wrong checks you're doing.

Comment: `is` and `is not` are not exact type checks. For example, `is` can still pass a check if the instance is of a derived type. You should use `Type` [in-]equality checks instead, using `.GetType()` to get the type of the instance.

Comment: What is `ClassValue`?  Wouldn't any object *not* be at least one of those types?  The condition could only be `false` if the same object is simultaneously *both* of those types.

Comment: @Trevor Well, this worked! Thank you! That was such a simple solution. Altough, i really tought a had already tried this.

Comment: Following on David's point, an object could simultaneously be both those types (in terms of `is` and `is not` tests) if one of those types derives from the other and the instance is of the derived type. Please show the class definitions for those two types.

Comment: @MomoVR you're welcome, but I would take the other comments into strong consideration as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood the boolean expression.

Suppose `value` is of type `BuiltInClass`:

Then

- `value is not BuiltInClass` will be false.
- `value is not ClassValue`   will be true.

Thus

```
value is not BuiltInClass || value is not ClassValue
```

resolves to

```
false || true => true
```

You "fixed" this by using `if (!(value is BuiltInClass || value is ClassValue))` instead, but that is NOT equivalent to your original code!

It would be equivalent to this:

```
if (value is not BuiltInClass && value is not ClassValue)
```

Note the use of `&&` instead of `||`.

For more information about boolean transforms, see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

In particular, note the transformation:

```
not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B)
```

Your fix is `not (A or B)`, but you could have fixed it by changing it to `(not A) and (not B)` as per De Morgan's laws.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was happy when i managed to fix it, but i still did not understand why it didn't work in the first place. This was a very clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to the comment section.
So i changed `if (value is not BuiltInClass || value is not ClassValue)`
to `if (!(value is BuiltInClass || value is ClassValue))` and now it works.

Comment: (Just to have mentioned it) An equivalent to that expression is `if (value is not BuiltInClass && value is not ClassValue)`, which is your original expression with `||` replaced by `&&`.